# xmlstarlet: Invalid expression: [xpath] compilation error: element for-each*

Tags: xml, bash, xml-parsing, xmlstarlet

There is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CurrentUsage xmlns="http://www.vmware.com/vcloud/v1.5" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.vmware.com/vcloud/v1.5 http://cloud.com/api/v1.5/schema/master.xsd">
    <Link rel="up" href="cloudurl" type="application/vnd.vmware.vcloud.vm+xml"/>
    <Metric name="cpu.usage.average" unit="PERCENT" value="3.4"/>
    <Metric name="cpu.usage.maximum" unit="PERCENT" value="3.4"/>
    <Metric name="cpu.usagemhz.average" unit="MEGAHERTZ" value="81.0"/>
    <Metric name="mem.usage.average" unit="PERCENT" value="15.99"/>
    <Metric name="disk.provisioned.latest" unit="KILOBYTE" value="503337805"/>
    <Metric name="disk.used.latest" unit="KILOBYTE" value="290391113"/>
</CurrentUsage>
```

I'm using xmlstarlet tool, and able to get list of values with:

```
xmlstarlet sel  -t -v //@value  test.xml
```

But I really stuck with getting particular value by name of metric (as an example for "cpu.usage.average").
I've read tons of examples, tried to use expressions like:

```
xmlstarlet sel  -t -m "//[@name='cpu.usage.average']" -v //@value test.xml
```

But this drops me into:

> ```
> Invalid expression: //[@name='cpu.usage.average'] 
> compilation error: element for-each*
> ```

How do I get particular value in such simple case?

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath is malformed.  Use `//*[@name='cpu.usage.average']` for `-m` as a fix (and also to bypass namespaces -- otherwise you'll have to declare a namespace prefix) and `@value` for `-v`.

Altogether, this xmlstarlet command

```
xmlstarlet sel  -t -m "//*[@name='cpu.usage.average']" -v @value test.xml
```

will return

```
3.4
```

for your XML, as requested.